# How to resolve ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(129)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum using ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My project was working fine, I didn't do anything in the code and after a few days the same code showed an error on console that is attached below [Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MebEY.png)

and my code side is attached below

```
string webUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
var options = new ChromeOptions()
{
   BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
   AcceptInsecureCertificates = true
};

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Drive\Projects\Web-Scraping-Fb-messenger-master1\Web-Scraping-Fb-messenger-master\Web Scarpping\Classes", options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webUrl);

var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
element.SendKeys("myemail");
element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));
element.SendKeys("mypassword");

element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Log In']"));
element.Click();
string link = string.Empty;
string grpname = string.Empty;
```

and on debugging it shows a selenium timeout error.
So my question is, how can I resolve the error:

```
ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(129)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum
```

Chrome Browser Version : 78.0.3904.108 
Chrome Driver Version  : 78.0.3904.105

Comment: Please add your code into the question as text instead of image. It will be easy for others to copy and test. Also, let us know the both chrome and chrome driver version you are uding.

Comment: @stud3nt i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk Class

The [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394308(v%3Dvs.85)) raw performance data class provides raw data from performance counters that monitor hard or fixed disk drives on a computer where disks are used to store file, program, and paging data and are read to retrieve these items, and written to record changes to them.

---

As per [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/06/18/reasons-why-the-error-enumeration-of-the-files-failed-may-occur-during-system-state-backup/) article this error:

```
ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(129)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.
```

may occur during due to either of the following factors:

1. An invalid path.
2. Invalid characters in the path.
3. Syntax formatting of the path.
4. A valid path on SAN drives of a Failover Cluster.

---

### This usecase

Your code trial was near perfect. However while passing the *absolute path* of the **ChromeDriver** you need to add the **name** of the *WebDriver* variant as well i.e. **`chromedriver`**. So effectively the line of code will be:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Drive\Projects\Web-Scraping-Fb-messenger-master1\Web-Scraping-Fb-messenger-master\Web Scarpping\Classes\chromedriver", options);
```

Comment: It didn't help as by using chromedriver () it already append that chromedriver to the path. However, as you have suggested, I implemented it and then the path appends chromedriver two times which is not desired.
Thanks for showing interest.